# Any Asynchronous Training Methods for GAN?

Tags: gan

GAN sometimes get really unstable with the high dimensional data. Can we train GAN is Asynchronous manner? It's like we have one master Generator and Discriminator. But we actually update it asynchronously with gradients from a number of slaves generators and discriminators.

Comment: Is there any reason the typical async multi-gpu training algorithms wouldn't carry over to gans?

Comment: well, theoretically I there is no wrong right? Like there is a master Discriminator and a generator and slaves updating on different tasks.